# Since the Room of Requirement has windows in some of its settings

Tags: harry-potter

Since the Room of Requirement has windows in some of its settings (multivarious appearances), would there be a change on the outside or is it magically enchanted like the Enchanted Ceiling?

To extend the first part of the question further, if it caused a change on the outside, why don't people notice the outside appearance?

Comment: Without wanting to point out the obvious, this magical room in a magical castle that magically appears could possibly be using some sort of magic to conceal itself

Comment: What he said...

Comment: Windows in the movies or in the books?